# How to filter based on previous queryset results Django

Tags: django, django-views, django-filter

At the moment I have 2 separate querysets rendering independently of each other on the same page.

`Q1`=`users`

`Q2`=`f`

`Q1` returns all users within a user-posted radius (`request.POST`).

`Q2` returns a `django_filters.FilterSet` depending on the filter chosen (hair color, age, etc) (`request.GET`)

`Q2` should only filter the results of `Q1`. I would like to keep it all on the same page, as opposed to redirect to different urls.

If someone could explain the simplest way of doing this, I would be most grateful.

views.py

```
class ConnectView(View):
    template_name = 'connect/home.html'
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        filter = ProfileFilter(request.GET.getlist('filter'))
        context = {
            'users': User.objects.exclude(username=request.user),
            'filter': filter
        }
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if 'latitude' in request.POST and 'longitude' in request.POST:
            try:
                location = Location(latitude=request.POST['latitude'], longitude=request.POST['longitude'], user = request.user)
                location.save()
            except:
                return JsonResponse({'message': 'location already stored!'})

        if 'radius' in request.POST:
            radius_km = request.POST.get('radius', 0)
            queryset = User.objects.annotate(
                radius_sqr=pow(models.F('loc__latitude') -
                request.user.loc.latitude, 2) + pow(models.F('loc__longitude') -
                request.user.loc.longitude, 2)
                ).filter(
                radius_sqr__lte=pow(int(radius_km) / 9, 2)
                ).exclude(username=request.user)
            filter = ProfileFilter(request.POST, queryset=queryset)
            messages.success(request, f'See the results of your search below.')
            return render(request, self.template_name)

        else:
            return render(request, self.template_name)
```

filters.py

```
class ProfileFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = {
            'age': ['exact'],
            'interest': ['exact'],
        }
```

connecthome.html

```
  <form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <h4>Enter a Distance.</h4>
    <input type="number" name="radius">
    {{ filter.form|crispy }}
    <button type="submit">Search.</button>
  </form>

    {% if filter %}
        {% for profile in filter %}
            <h5>{{ profile.user.first_name }}</h5>
            <p>{{ profile.age }}</p>
        {% empty %}
            <h1>No results, try again?</h1>
        {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
        {% for user in users %}
            <h5>{{ user.first_name }}</h5>
            <p>{{ user.profile.age }}</p>
        {% empty %}
            <h1>No results, try again?</h1>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
```

Comment: the page is returned either as a result of a GET request or of a POST request, it can't be both. Put everything in one form and submit all information (the filter choice and the distance) using either GET or POST. Probably a GET is more appropriate since you're not writing anything to the database.

Comment: Yes I did look that up and see that I couldn't combine both requests..okay thank you for your help, I really appreciate it. How would I combine the `filters.py` `django_filters` and the `radius` queryset in `forms.py`?

Comment: Pass the radius QuerySet from your `POST` method to your filter where you get `radius` from `request.GET` instead of `request.POST`.

Comment: So you are saying it is possible to just pass the `radius` queryset to `filters.py` which would then render out one FilterSet and be processed by `request.GET` (like the other filter information is currently)? Would you mind showing me what passing the radius queryset to `filters.py` would look like?

Comment: I meant to move the code your now have in `post()` to your `get()` method (and completely delete the `post()`, sorry that wasn't clear in my comment. So first you check for `radius`, build your queryset depending on whether or not `radius` is in `request.GET` and then use that queryset to filter your users using the filters.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I have updated my question to show the other part of my `post`  because the `radius` queryset is dependent on the values from the `request.POST` for `latitude and longitude`, how would I pass these to the `GET` radius queryset?

Comment: your template should have only one form and all data should be submitted using method=get. So latitude and longitude will be in `request.GET`, same as radius.

Comment: Yes I see, however I was posting `lat and lon` to a `Location` model along with user info

Comment: ah sorry, now i see you're saving that. Then change to use one form with method=post and move the code from your get method to your post method. your filters will be in request.POST then. And you then keep the `get` method as it is now since this returns the unfiltered set of users.

Comment: Yes thank you so much, I understand more..but I'm a bit confused because initially I set the `radius` queryset to `context = {'users': queryset}` so that it would render out the unfiltered set of users if no radius was inputted, but the `radius` queryset if a radius was entered (I'm running a `{% for user in users %}` to populate the page). But now because I have added another `queryset = ProfileFilter(request.POST` etc after `if 'radius' in request.POST:` it's not rendering out the `{{ filter.form }}` but is still filtering by `radius` Am I doing it properly?

Comment: I guess it's not showing the `ProfileFilter` form because it's no longer in `GET` but how can I assign both `ProfileFilter` queryset and `radius` queryset to users in the same `request.POST`?

Comment: `f = ProfileFilter(request.POST, queryset=queryset)` (where `queryset` is either the one from 'radius' or `Profile.objects.exclude(user=request.user)` if 'radius' was not posted.

Comment: @dirkgroten I've added that line of code and have updated my code above to reflect what I think you are saying, would you kindly look at it?

Comment: It's now working although `request.POST` returns the correct queryset in the terminal, it returns `no results` on the screen which is obviously because of my `if then` logic. If you post your comment as an answer I will gladly accept it as correct. Again, thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your template to only have one form that POSTs both radius and the filters. Then in your post method, use the location/radius to create the queryset that you pass to your filter:

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    # default queryset, users is needed in context based on your get() method
    users = User.objects.exclude(username=request.user.username)
    queryset = Profile.objects.exclude(user=request.user)  
    if 'latitude' in request.POST and 'longitude' in request.POST:
        # code to store Location

    if 'radius' in request.POST:
        radius_km = request.POST.get('radius', 0)
        # reduce queryset by users within radius
        queryset = queryset.annotate(
            radius_sqr=pow(models.F('user__loc__latitude') -
            request.user.loc.latitude, 2) + pow(models.F('user__loc__longitude') -
            request.user.loc.longitude, 2)
            ).filter(
            radius_sqr__lte=pow(int(radius_km) / 9, 2)
            )
        messages.success(request, f'See the results of your search below.')

    filter = ProfileFilter(request.POST, queryset=queryset)
    return render(request, self.template_name, {'filter': filter, 'users': users})
```

Comment: Okay one last question, the current user is not being excluded from the results, even with `.exclude(username=request.user)` why is that line necessary?

Comment: If I have `{'filter': f}` in the get method?

Comment: in get() you called the variable `f` in my post() I called it `filter` (I never use variable names like `f` because they don't have any meaning). It doesn't matter.

Comment: sorry something's not correct here, the queryset passed to `ProfileFilter` should be on `Profile` objects. How is `Profile` related to `User`?

Comment: And sorry, I meant the whole line `queryset = users = User.objects.exclude(username=request.user) `

Comment: I mean what's the relationship? OneToOne?

Comment: Yes it is a OneToOne

Comment: ok, changed your filter. Note how I changed the queryset ('user__loc') to filter profiles rather than users.

Comment: I'm just wanting to understand why that line is necessary because it seems to cause more problems / changes. Without it, everything works fine, the only thing is that the current user is still being returned on the page. With that line, I get the error `local variable 'queryset' referenced before assignment` and the current user is still being shown on the page.

Comment: I changed the line. But the error you're seeing is not possible with the code I'm showing, so your code must be different. your error says you're using a variable `queryset` that hasn't been assigned, in my code it's assigned in the top of the post method .

Comment: I've gone through and double checked to make sure my code is the same but when I submit the `request.POST` I get `Cannot resolve keyword 'interest' into field.`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188675/discussion-between-dirkgroten-and-trilla).